# Need to provide indent to submenu over the main menu

Tags: html, css

For indent i tried `float:right`, but only text is moving not the entire component.

For example: In the File main menu, its submenu New and Open should be indent to rightside as below.

```
File
----New
----Open
```

But it look like, which i don't require.

```
File
New
Open
```

Please refer below jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/4v4K6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you won't require this level of specific selector, but it will provide you clearly of what you are trying to target

```
nav > ul > li > a + div > ul > li > a {
    text-indent: 15px; /* Can use padding-left as well */
}
```

In the above selector am selecting `ul` which is direct child to `nav` further selecting direct child `li` going further selecting `div` which is adjacent to `a` tag, and rest is self explanatory, same applies like the previous explanation.

You can write the above like, only specificity differs

```
nav a + div > ul > li > a {
    text-indent: 15px; /* Can use padding-left as well */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4v4K6/2/)

Comment: Thanks.... i tried this option but only to nav, hope which i failed. Anyhow thanks for your post.

Answer (score 1):

So you can target the hover state of the li and then apply the rule like this:

```
nav ul li:hover div { margin-left: 20px; }
```

Comment: Thanks.... i given +1 upvote for your solution which also works fine. But @Mr.Alien posted first.